# Microsoft Edge Chromium Extension and UWP/WinRT

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, microsoft-edge, chromium

Is it possible to invoke routines in a UWP or WinRT application from within a Microsoft Edge Chromium extension.  The latest documentation says that it is possible to invoke native API code, but it does not explain how to do this nor does it explain the limitations of such an exploit.

Comment: Apparently the new Chromium capability does not work with AppServices in that we cannot get a UWP app to act as a MS Edge Extension unless it has an extension configured via the registry (meaning HKLM/yada/yada/yada).  This is a gap in capabilities that I hope Microsoft addresses soon.